# django app that uses two other applications

Tags: django, django-apps

I am building a marketing application.

There is a **participants** application and an **advertisers** application.
Advertisers propose participants to join **campaigns**.

Now I want to create **campaigns**: 
Advertisers create campaigns and consult their own campaigns (they have basic information about the participants who have joined their campaign) .
Participants consult campaigns, join campaigns and answer questions.

My question is: should I create **one application campaign** with all those functionalities inside? Or should I put the participants functionalities in the **participant application** and the advertisers functionalities in the **advertisers application**?

**EDIT :**
**participants** and **advertisers** have their own application to manage their own profile (unrelated to campaigns).

Comment: Unless it's an insane amount of customizations for the functionalities of each, you would be just fine putting all of the functions into one application. However, I would split them up into their own separate models.

Comment: It depends on whether **advertisers / participants** have functionalities that are unrelated with **campaigns**. If other parts of your project also involve **advertisers**, probably a standalone app; if **advertisers** don't make any sense outside **campaigns**, just put it in **campaigns**

Comment: @jph, @ZZY: Thanks for your comments, I have finally adopted your solution: one application for the `campaigns`. `Advertisers` and `Participants` are two other apps, cause they are used for other things too. Solved!